# SVN: how to update deep folder structure?

Tags: svn

I have a web app that uses a third party component made up of many files and directories (CKEditor). When a new version comes out, I copy/overwrite new files over existing ones. That takes care of added and modified content, but if the new distribution is missing a file that was there before, I'll end up keeping the stale copy. Since SVN relies on .svn folders for state, I can't just delete the old root folder and copy in the new.

Is there an easy/standard way to handle this sort of mass update with SVN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use `rsync` with a `--exclude=.svn` for this type of thing.

But i think CKEditor has a public svn repo so in that case I would use an `svn:externals` pegged to a particular release and then run the build script to the published directory thats on the web root so my repo might look like:

```
trunk/
  web/
    index.html
    js/
      ckeditor/
    images/
    css/
  lib/
    ckeditor/ (svn:externals to CK_EDITOR_SVN_URL/tags/some-version)
```

This way i cn just switch the external and do an svn up. This is particularly useful if the project your external is targeting does versioned branches where the continuously integrate BC updates. This way anytime you run an svn up you get the latest bug fixes and can just rebuild. Whether or not thats a good idea depend on the way the development of a particular project works so youll want to read through the developer docs before doing this.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of the external repo support. Is that something TortoiseSVN can handle?

Comment: @Michael: i dunno i work on OS X and Ubunutu mostly. Im sure Tortise supports using an external, but it may not have a menu item to do `propedit`/`propset`, in which case youd need to use the command line client to set it up or change the external location, but that shouldnt be too much of a hassle as youre not going to be doing it too often.

Comment: TortoiseSVN does not have a specific support for svn:externals, but it does have generic CRUD support for SVN properties.

Comment: I am going to go with this answer because it doesn't involve having to install PERL.

For anyone interested, here's the equivalent of the rsync command on Windows:

`robocopy <source> <target> /s /purge /xd ".svn"`

where `<source>` and `<target>` should be replaced with appropriate folders.

Answer (score 0):

Using [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html) is one alternative. If you prefer to keep a snapshot of third party libraries in your own repository, however, you should read up on the concept of [vendor branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html) in SVN. There is a standard Perl script ([svn_load_dirs.pl](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html#svn.advanced.vendorbr.svn_load_dirs)) available for bulk loading third party code into your SVN repository that handles deletes properly.

Comment: thank you for the pointer. Vendor branches more or less describes the general algorithm I already follow. It mentiones the issue of orphaned files in passing, but doesn't really address it. Doesn't sound like the PERL script does either.

Comment: The PERL script will, in fact handle orphaned files. I have used it many times. You give it a non-versioned directory containing the new source tree and it checks out the old source tree, does add/update/delete logic with some user feedback, then commits the new source tree back to SVN. It has an option for tagging each new version as well. Then you can use the new vendor branch to merge the changes into your trunk branch. It can get a bit involved, however, and I can certainly understand if it's not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for following up, this certainly wasn't obvious from the web page.